# The created svc Service is always SOAP

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

i am trying to create REST webservice:

Print.svc:

```
 <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService1.Print" CodeBehind="Print.svc.cs" %>
```

IPrint.cs:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPrint
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="GET",
        ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate="print/{id}")]
    string Printer(string id);
}
```

Print.cs

```
public string Printer(string id)
{
    return "hola" + id;
}
```

And the web config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <configuration>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
         <service name="WcfService1.Print" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IPrint" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
         </service>
        </services>
     <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">         
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>          
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>                
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

So,if i enter: /Print.svc/Printer/chau
i should have : "hola chau"

Insted, i get:
"Endpoint not found"
And, if i enter /Print.svc:

```
You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this     using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

svcutil.exe http://localhost:8415/Print.svc?wsdl

You can also access the service description as a single file:
http://localhost:8415/Print.svc?singleWsdl
```

So its a SOAP WebService!! I want it rest!
Which is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a little mistake:

```
   [WebInvoke(Method="GET",
        ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate="print/{id}")]
```

UriTemplate should be "Printer/{id}"!!!!

Anyway, i dont understand why i can do a wsdl to a rest webservice???

Comment: REST does not have the concept of WSDL - that's one of the big plusses of SOAP. REST has nothing comparable right now-

Comment: I know, the problem was that i was being able to do a wsdl to the rest service.